# How to decode a http request packet with okio/okhttp

Tags: android, vpn, okhttp, okio

#### Can I use Okio and/or OkHTTP to decode a packet read from ParcelFileDescriptor ?

I'm trying to write a `VpnService` based ad-blocker on android.

I've found a few open source projects using `VpnService` ([NetGuard](https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard), [NetKnight](https://github.com/pencil-box/NetKnight)), so I could learn from them.

And I known OkHTTP could make a request using just `url` and `method`, which means it could understood some thing like `GET http://stackoverflow.com Http/1.1`, and transform it to a real TCP/IP based request, even decode response. So I tried to read some source code of Okio to found out what it does, but failed.

So I was wondering if I could use Okio's component to decode/encode TCP/IP packets?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Create a Socket using the normal APIs, then use `Okio.source(Socket)` and `Okio.sink(Socket)` to get streams from it. Also don't forget that you can buffer these streams with `Okio.buffer()`.

Comment: How's the socket come from? The VpnService returned with a ParcelFileDescriptor.